# C# error CS0017

Tags: c#

cuento con 2 pequeños programas en c# (estoy aprendidendo)
y se muestra lo sig:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Previamente tengo una clase donde estoy acomulando todo el codigo que me gustaria tener por separado pero por ese error que sale no puedo hacer multiples clases

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. No uses imágenes para mostrar código. Haz clic en [edit] y mejora tu pregunta cambiando las imágenes por texto (copiar y pegar). Además, todos los mensajes de error también debes copiarlos en texto en tu pregunta.

Comment: "Main" es una palabra clave para el programa que se ejecuta y solo puede haber 1, este indica donde empieza la ejecución el código del programa, todas las otras clases tienen que tener "constructor" o bien "main" con minúscula

Comment: @LPZadkiel Para ser rigurosos, lo que señalas no es cierto. Puedes tener varios `Main` pero debes indicar el punto de entrada al compilar, tal como dice el mensaje de error de las imagenes

Comment: El problema, mas alla de las discusiones de ahi arriba, que son ciertas, es que no tenes 2 pequeños programas. Tenes una solucion, que contiene un proyecto (esto si podria denominarse programa) con dos clases, que parecen, por lo que se ve en las imagenes (no pongas el codigo en imagenes) que son dos ejercicios distintos, deberian ser 2 proyectos distintos, y ahi si, vas a tener 2 programas distintos... Aca lo que tenes son dos clases, que no es lo mismo. Y si tenes una confusion entre clase y programa, ya ya, a leer al respecto

Answer (score 0):

Probá poniendo esto dentro de PropertyGroup en el archivo .csproj

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <StartupObject>MyNamespace.MyClassWithMain</StartupObject>
</PropertyGroup>
```

con tu Namespace y clase quedaria algo asi:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <StartupObject>ProyectoCSharp.Class1_HelloWorld</StartupObject>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: No le has explicado nada